# Is it an ok practice to change an ID using javascript if the element is unique?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an unordered list, where I am using an ID to identify the current list item that was last clicked. On click of a different item, I am using js to switch the id to a different item in the list, so that styling could be applied.

It seems intuitive to me that a unique item that can only be used once (a selected li item) should be identified as an ID, and that is why I did that, but I was told it is bad practice to do so.

Comment: Do you also remove the id from previously selected element?

Comment: Am I will prefer the use of a classname like `clicked` ... If you want to apply that function later on another list or item the ID can be a problem.

Comment: To me the question seems to be: Should I use ID for styling? The answer being: apply a class instead.

Comment: If an ID can refer to different elements at different times, then it doesn't refer to a unique element, and isn't really an ID. Similarly you could use my driving licence, but you'd be being naughty.

Comment: YES, I remove the id... then add it to a different item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't do so. This rather seems an opportunity for you to discover [HTML 5's data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes), which you can use for both CSS styling (using attribute selector) and JS use (with `dataset` or jQuery's `.data()` method).
[Quick definition from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) :

> HTML5 is designed with extensibility in mind for data that should be
>   associated with a particular element but need not have any defined
>   meaning. data-* attributes allow us to store extra information on
>   standard, semantic HTML elements without other hacks such as
>   classList, non-standard attributes, extra properties on DOM, or
>   setUserData.

In HTML side :

```
<!-- You can use data without value, and just test its presence -->
<li data-selected> 
    ...
</li>
```

In CSS :

```
li[data-selected]{
   ...
}
```

Comment: This is a valid method too and might make a lot of sense if you're building an app for example.

Answer (score 3):

Your question actually has a couple of interesting components, let me try to answer them as good as I can :-)

1. "Is it an ok practice to change an ID using javascript if the element is unique?"

You could say it's a justifiable case, if the element really is unique, then there's no real harm in "moving" the ID with JavaScript.

**BUT**

In your description you touch on something more fundamental:

2. "On click of a different item, I am using js to switch the id to a different item in the list, so that styling could be applied."

If this is the case (you change the ID for styling), then I'd recommend using a class instead. People previously already gave you a good hint, something like an "is-active" class would be very useful as it's less specfic than an ID, can be used on multiple items if needed and if you use classes that determine a state (like "is-active", "has-children", "is-animating", etc.), it's really easy to re-use them in later parts of code as well and it is clear what the element is doing at the moment.

A little code for reference:

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li>Some item</li>
  <li class="is-active">Some item</li>
  <li>Some item</li>
  <li>Some item</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.is-active {
  color: #eee;
  background-color: #222;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
// You probably want a bit more specific selector, but it's just an example.
$('li').on('click', function() {

  var $element = $(this),
      $elements = $('li');

  if (!$element.hasClass('is-active')) {
    $elements.removeClass('is-active');
    $element.addClass('is-active');
  }

});
```

Comment: `$elements.toggleClass('is-active',false).filter($element).toggleClass('is-active',true);`

Comment: I would up vote this if I did not disagree with the "there's no real harm in..." part.

Comment: Feel free to explain

Answer (score 0):

Since you might need to reference the specific id of an element at some future point, changing it is probably a bad idea.  In your case it would be better to just apply a class to the last item clicked.