# $('#next').on('click', function () not working when id changed with document.getElementById("save").id = "next"

Tags: javascript, jquery

My issue is simple, and I have an idea of why it might not work but I could use some advice or alternative options.

Essentially, what I am trying to achieve is having the same button be responsive for the save, and once saved is clicked and processed correctly, then I want the id to change to next and perform an on-click event once the button is clicked again with the new id. The id change part below is in a functioning if statement so that is not the issue, I left it out so it was more readable.

```
document.getElementById("save").id = "next";
```

I tried showing and hiding two separate buttons, but I would like the buttons to be in the exact same place.

```
document.getElementById("save").id = "next";

$('#next').on('click', function () {

     // My code here

}
```

Comment: And what would you expect here? You put a click handler on a  button then essentially removed it,  Use two buttons, hide one then swap the display/visibility.  Position has nothing to do with having two buttons.

Comment: I did that previously, the buttons show up in different spots on the page. I was just looking for a simple solution to having the buttons in the same exact place.

Comment: You have to use event delegation if you're changing IDs dynamically, just like when you're creating elements dynamically.

Comment: Works fine for me:  https://jsfiddle.net/w7poen45/

Comment: Changing IDs dynamically is bad design. Why don't you just set a global variable that the click handler checks?

Comment: @devlincarnate - yea because your fiddle attaches the click handler after you make a new button id.

Comment: As mentioned above, changing an element id is bad design.  Another alternative is to uses classes -- add and remove a class

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss - ok, so the solution is to attach the click handler after changing the Id

Comment: No the solution is to have two buttons and show/hide them when the first is clicked OR just have one and change the text only - depending upon use etc. you could also use a `data` property to hold the "state of things" to make it a single button

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss - I guess that depends on what your definition of solution is.  Something that works vs something that is designed well.  Switching classes is another solution.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27041673/125981

Answer (score -1):

Try using this `$('#save').attr('id', 'next');`.

If that doesn’t work, maybe assign a class instead. Like:

```js
$("#save").attr("class","next");

$('.next').on('click', function () {

     // My code here

});
```

Comment: Don't use curly quotes in code.

Comment: Thank you. Stinks how iPhone automatically does quotes like that, so I fixed the answer

Comment: `$(‘#save’).attr(‘id’, ‘next’);.` no, probably not, id is a property that is unique on a page.

Comment: I thought so. I usually use classes more often for this kind of thing