# Why does my button not click when I change its id attribute?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I changed the attribute id of a button. The old id #slide_save_button has a light blue color, and the new id #slide_save_button_open has a dark blue color, which changes when it is supposed to. But when I attempt to click the button (by referring to its new id #slide_save_button_open) it won't execute the console.log("clicked"). Why?

```
$("#catName").on("input", function(){
  if( $("#catName").val().length > 0 ){
    $("#slide_save_button").attr('id', 'slide_save_button_open');
  } else {
    $("#slide_save_button_open").attr('id', 'slide_save_button');
  }
});



$("#slide_save_button_open").on("click", function(){
  console.log("clicked");
});
```

Comment: That's just a bad strategy. The purpose of an ID is to _identify_. Why would you change it? In doing so you break all event handlers. Use a class for that instead, or check the value of the input _at click time_ (a better approach in general).

Comment: because the event is bound when the code is run. It does not keep on looking for elements that match.

Comment: A much better approach would be to use css classes for styles, not the ID.

Comment: You'll still need event delegation though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach fails because the code looks for the element at that moment in time. When it finds it, it binds it. The code does not keep looking for elements.

To do it your way, you would need to use event delegation.

```js
$("#catName").on("input", function() {
  if ($("#catName").val().length > 0) {
    $("#slide_save_button").attr('id', 'slide_save_button_open');
  } else {
    $("#slide_save_button_open").attr('id', 'slide_save_button');
  }
});

$(document).on("click", "#slide_save_button_open", function() {
  console.log("clicked");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm">
  <label for="catName">Name:</label>
  <input id="catName" name="catName"/>
  <button type="button" id="slide_save_button" name="slide_save_button">Run</button>
</form>
```

Now changing the id is not really the best solution. You probably should just take a "validation" approach and use a variable to hold the state or you can use a class.

```js
const btn = $("#slide_save_button");

$("#catName").on("input", function() {
  btn.toggleClass("open", $("#catName").val().length > 0);
});

btn.on("click", function() {
  if (btn.hasClass("open")) {
    console.log("clicked");
  } else {
    console.log("need to fill in");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm">
  <label for="catName">Name:</label>
  <input id="catName" name="catName" />
  <button type="button" id="slide_save_button" name="slide_save_button">Run</button>
</form>
```

But you could just use HTML5 validation

```js
const form = $("#myForm");
form.on("submit", function (evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  console.log("clicked");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm">
  <label for="catName">Name:</label>
  <input id="catName" name="catName" required/>
  <button type="submit" id="slide_save_button" name="slide_save_button">Run</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

`$("#slide_save_button_open")` searches the DOM for an element which has that ID **right now**. You then add an event handler to it.

When you later change the ID, it doesn't retroactively delete the existing event handlers and rerun the original code to attach new ones.

---

You can achieve something like that with event delegation where you bind the event handler to an ancestor element and listen for a bubbled event.

```
$(document).on("click", "#slide_save_button_open", function () { .... });
```

You could also test for something about the element inside the event handler:

```
$("#slide_save_button").on("input", function(e) {
    if ( $(e.currentTarget).attr('id') === 'slide_save_button_open') {
```

---

That said, I'd recommend testing a different feature of the element and not changing the ID. It's still the same thing even if it is in a different state.

Take a look at the [Navigation Menu Button Example](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/examples/menu-button/menu-button-links.html). You could make use of `aria-expanded="true"`.

Answer (score 0):

Base on this https://stackoverflow.com/a/27041899/15924734 it's not ok to change ID attribute. For what you need, you can use  `addClass()`, `removeClass()` & `toggleClass()`

Also for dynamic elements you can use this:

```
$(document).on("click", "#test-element", function() {
   console.log("clicked");
});
```

Comment: While this is good advice, it doesn't address the problem (which is about controlling if an event handler triggers based on the state of an element). Moving the change from the ID to a class will still mean it won't fire because the "active" class isn't on the element at the start. This should be a comment, not an answer.